# How should I extract a username from a SAML response?

Tags: saml

I am writing a SAML SP and can not figure out a uniform way to extract a user's username/login from the SAML response returned by the IdP. It looks like this information can be in a variety of places (NameID, Attribute) from different IdP's, and the IdP metadata does not seem to offer any hints.

Right now, I am using an extra configuration directive containing XPath for retrieving the username, but would like to eliminate this. Is this something I can specify in SP metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unrelated to SAML Meta Data, but a proprietary configuration of your SP.
As you stated, you could either use the value of the NamedID or the value of an Attribute Statement. If your SP allows to do SSO with different IdPs this setting could be IdP-entity based. E.g. one IdP may only support the 'transient NameId Format' then you can not use the value as it's an opaque handle which must change all the time. To get some idea you may look at OpenAM's doc, it is using an 'Account Mapper' for this purpose (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/admin-guide/chap-federation#sp-account-mapper)